# Statistics checkbox disabled

Tags: enterprise-miner

I'm following the walkthrough called [Data Mining Using SAS
Enterprise Miner: A Case Study Approach](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/emcs/66392/PDF/default/emcs.pdf) (PDF).

On pdf page 45 it says to check the statistics box (While viewing variables in the Transform Node). However, this checkbox is disabled:

[image]

**How do I get access to that checkbox?**

- I read that it might be the [Advanced Advisor](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Data-Mining/Enabling-the-quot-statistics-quot-check-box-in-the-variable/td-p/126717), but it doesn't specify how to turn that on.
- It also suggests that I run the node, then I'd be able to see it. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally figured it out:

When you create a new data source, in the **Data Source Wizard -- Step 4 of 8 Metadata Advisor Options** you will have the option of selecting `Basic` or `Advanced`.

You want to select **`Advanced`**:

[image]